# How to use template template as template argument properly?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have this code with error:

```cpp
template <typename T1>
struct A {
    template <typename T2>
    struct B {
        using type = char /* actually some class depending on T1 and T2 */;
    };
    template <typename T2>
    using type = B<T2>;
};

template <template <typename> class TT>
struct C {
    template <typename T>
    using type = TT<T> /* actually something more complex */;
};

template <typename T>
struct D {
    using type = typename C<typename A<T>::type>::type;
//                                             ^
// g++: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list
// for ‘template<template<class> class TT> struct C’
};

int main() {}
```

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is that `A<T>::type` is `template <class> class`, not simple `typename` as I declared. I tried remove keyword `typename` after `A<T>::type` or replace it on `template` or `template <class> class`, but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem? I don't want significantly edit code of structs and *really* don't want declare `A` with 2 template arguments or define `B` outside `A` or something else which significantly change `A` and `B` due to logic of program but ready consider any helpful idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `template`, but in a different place:

```
using type = typename C<A<T>::template type>::type;
//                            ^~~~~~~~
```

IIRC, it becomes optional and deprecated in C++23 (that is, `template` followed by an identifier without `<...>` after it).

Comment: It was [never clear](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1478) that this use of `template` did anything, and the deprecation presumably shares the defect report status.